# How should I implement a "like" counter to my site? (not facebook)

Tags: php, mysql

In my website users can post submissions, and I want other users to be able to do what would be my equivalent of facebook's "likes".

But I don't know how to implement this. My main problem is that I need to prevent uses from liking the same thing more than once.

I was planning to add a long string into the database entry of each submission, for example "userid:rating/userid:rating/userid:rating". But I think that would be highly inefficient, because I would need to parse the string every time someone presses a button, and if there's lots of ratings then it would have to do a lot of work I think.

Should I make a separate table for ratings globally, and use the submission ID to link them to the right thing, or what? I feel it would be very inefficient to make mysql dig through the whole database and look for all individual rating entries that have a matching ID every time someone opens a submission page...

Comment: No! Don't use this "long string" approach: make a separate table... your `I feel it would be very inefficient` is groundless as long as that table is properly indexed

Comment: You're right, the "long string" will be HIDEOUSLY inefficient. Read up about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: `JOIN`s in MySQL are not as inefficient as you think.  As long as you use `INDEX`es correctly, it should be nice and quick!

Comment: MySQL is VERY good at relational database queries, its what is was designed for. you should 100% use a separate table for the likes, this table should include the user's ID, and the post ID, then the query will be a simple `SELECT * FROM likes WHERE user_id=$userID && post_id=$post_id`  If that comes back with a result, de-activate the like button / invalidate any like request.

Comment: Properly [normalize your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and **DO NOT** use the slash separated string method.

Comment: He is asking, no need to down vote his question

Answer (score 2):

You create another table: `submission_rating`. Three columns would suffice: `rating`, `submission_id` and `user_id`.

Someone presses like, you do an an `INSERT`. But, before you do the insert, you check whether or not this particular user has already liked this submission. If the user has, you remove the like. If it does not, you insert the rating.

edit: As two gentleman below suggested, rather than relying on another check, go for the `UNIQUE` index. Make sure you catch the error and properly show it when trying to insert. Boldly said, `if(!$insert) {}`.

Comment: A `UNIQUE` index will block duplicate inserts.

Comment: True, but it's better practice to make sure it doesn't even get to that. Get it to work first, then you can add the UNIQUE index.

Comment: actually that's what unique indices are for. Depends if you want more code to maintain to make a duplicate check happen twice at more cpu cost.

Comment: Add the `UNIQUE` index first and you'll never have problems, plus you can just `INSERT IGNORE` which will disregard duplicate inserts automatically instead of producing errors. The index also makes it very fast to determine if a user has favorited something or not, plus produce a list of things the user has favorited.

Comment: You are right. I stand corrected.Thanks guys.